# Connecting external data to ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis

I'm very new to ArcGIS, I need to developed some sort of custom web part for SharePoint where i could use the ArcGIS API's to leverage the map, filters, and potentially sharepoint components (document library, list item). All of the map data points reside in external data sources (SQL). Can anyone recommend me a particular API to use, i'm looking at silverlight, javascript and .Net but they all seem to have some limitations as what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Javascript API and Silverlight are both ok. Try to explain better what you want to do.

Comment: Example, how could i add new layer to my basemap with information pull from a webservice or direclty from a SQL table.